Mocking the new instance creation call inside a void method without using PowerMock
I have a class where inside a void method it does a new instance creation
public class BaseDao {
        protected void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
            this.defaultTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        }
}

Now in my Test Class for BaseDao i would like to return a mock when a new instance of JdbcTemplate is created with dataSource arguments instead of a new instance.
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class BaseDaoTest {
    
    @Mock
    private JdbcTemplate defaultTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testSetDataSource() throws SQLException {
        when(<what to do here?>).thenReturn(mockedDefaultTemplate) //here when new instance of JdbcTemplate is created i would like to return this mockedDefaultTemplate
    }
}

This is possible in PowerMock using whenNew however i don't want to use PowerMock because it does not have junit 5 support and in general i dont like powerMock.
Please advise how can i do this.

Perhaps you could do
public class BaseDao {
        protected void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
            setJdbcTemplate(new JdbcTemplate(dataSource));
        }

        protected void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcOperations defaultTemplate ) {
            this.defaultTemplate = defaultTemplate 
        }

        public void doSomethingFantastic() { ... }
}

Then your tests could do
JdbcOperations jdbcTemplate = Mockito.mock(JdbcOperations.class);
when(jdbcTemplate.foo()).thenReturn(bar);

BaseDao dao = new BaseDao();
dao.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
dao.doSomethingFantastic();


i cannot change the BaseDao Code

Is defaultTemplate private in BaseDao?
